# Wrapping paper input error message

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

The long error messages in paper-input overflow the screen. Please see the below jsbin for e.g.

http://jsbin.com/beyigocosi/edit?html,console,output

Just click submit without entering any values. I tried to fix it using the mixin paper-input-error without much success.

code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <base href="http://polymer-magic-server.appspot.com/components/">

  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-styles/paper-styles.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-material/paper-material.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-form/iron-form.html" rel="import">


  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<x-example></x-example>

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
    paper-material {
      padding: 24px;
    }
    paper-button {
      margin-top: 24px;
      background-color: var(--paper-red-400);
      color: var(--text-primary-color);
    }

  </style>
  <template>
    <form is="iron-form" 
          id="formTest" 
          action="/" 
          method="get"
          disable-native-validation-ui>
    <paper-material>
      <h2>Sample form</h2>
      <paper-input
        required
        type="text"
        error-message="This is a reallllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyyyyyy realllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyyyy lllllllllllllllllllllong error message that is going to overflow the screen which neeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeds to be fixed"
        label="Enter user name"
        name="username">
      </paper-input>
      <paper-input
        text="password"
        required
        error-message="This is a another realllllllllllllllllllllly reallllllllllyyyyyyyyyyyy lllllllllllllllllllllllong error message that is going to overflow the screen which neeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeds to be fixed"
        label="Enter password"
        name="password">
      </paper-input>
      <paper-button
        on-tap="submitForm">SUBMIT</paper-button>
    </paper-material>

  </form>

  </template>
  <script>

    // only need this when both (1) in the main document and (2) on non-Chrome browsers
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

      Polymer({
        is: "x-example",
        properties: {
          selected: {
            type: String,
            value: 'one'
          }
        },
        submitForm: function() {
          this.$.formTest.submit();
        }
      });
    });

  </script>
</dom-module>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: @stef - if you click submit in the e.g. its displays error message which overflows the form. I am trying to wrap the message within the form.

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to update the `white-space` property within `paper-input-error` from `nowrap` to `normal`. This can be done via [Custom CSS Properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#xscope-styling-details) -

```
paper-input {
  --paper-input-error: {
    white-space: normal;
  };
}
```

Also you might want to add `position: relative;` to it too so the error text doesn't overlap other elements underneath when it's long enough.

Comment: It adds two to three empty lines below the text field even when the error message is not displayed.

Comment: Because the content is reserved for the error text. You can probably try to collapse it when the validation hasn't been triggered, but doing so means the content will also *jump* a bit when additional text gets inserted in.

Comment: I cannot make lot of changes to paper-input-error. I raised this question in using polymer tags to figure out how to do this.